# Read from pipe large files C/Bash

Tags: c, bash, http, pipe, fifo

I am working on a `web server` in `C`. But for `http` request parsing and response I am using `bash`.

Communication between bash and server is going through `fifo pipes`.
I need to find a requested file like `/index.html` and send it through the pipe to server and then send it to client.

My code's looking like this:

```
bash:
cat $filename>/tmp/pipeToServer filename is something like index.html or image.jpg
```

And at server side I am reading it like:

```
pipe_r = open(/tmp/pipeToServer, O_RDONLY);
n = read(pipe_r, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
and buffer2 is char buffer[4096]
```

So my problem is that this is working only with small files like 1kb, but when the file is larger, I can't read the whole content at pipe because of a limit on the buffer size.

Comment: `read()` only reads the requested bytes (or less). So if you have larger input then you can use a loop with a separate larger buffer to copy into (or `malloc()` as necessary)and `read()` says no more input.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the size of your `buffer2` so that all the contents of the file are read. As of now maybe your buffer size is less than the contents of your file,so all values are not being read.